# Asymmetric ease of improvisation during modulation

Tags: theory, chord-progressions, improvisation, modulation

I've been learning about modes, and one thing I was interested in at first was to change modes while improvising (to get to know them better technically as well as to have a better understanding of what their flavour is). For instance, I improvised in minor pentatonic, and used its ambiguity with the relative minor modes to try to explore their differences. This lead me to question how to properly change modes in a convincing way, and even how to properly change key.

I don't know anything about the theory of modulation, but I wanted to try and experiment to figure out how it could be done.

---

I first picked two keys at random : **E aeolian** and **G# aeolian**.

I basically did what I think is a common-chord modulation. My idea was to pick the common notes between the two keys, and use them to transition from one key to the other. Here, the common notes are **B E F#**, which are a **Bsus4** triad, so I used that chord to transition between the two keys. Going ***to*** **E aeolian** I let **Bsus4** resolve to **Bm**, and going ***to*** **G# aeolian** I let **Bsus4** resolve to **B**.

I used this very simple progression (on a loop) and improvised in **E minor pentatonic/E aeolian**, going to **G# minor pentatonic/G# aeolian** and back, to keep it as simple as I could.

**Em Am | Em Am | Bsus4 B | G#m C#m | G#m C#m | Bsus4 Bm**

**My observation is that I managed to change key in a way that sounded pretty good (at least to me) when the change was from E to G#, but not the other way around, I found it much more difficult to sound even decent.**

---

- I thought it could be because **Bm** triad is **B D F#** and **F#** is not in **Em pentatonic**, while the **B** triad is **B D# F#** which are all in **G# pentatonic**. So I changed **F#** to the closest note in **Em pentatonic**, **G**, which means I'm left with a **G triad**. So I tried this :

  **Em Am | Em Am | Bsus4 B | G#m C#m | G#m C#m | Bsus4 G**

  But the chord themselves didn't sound that good (even if I tried to play **G** in first inversion to keep **B** at the bass, to have some sense of resolution for the suspended chord), and when I tried to improvise the problem remained.
- I thought it could be because of the resolution **sus4 -> minor** which isn't as appealing as **sus4 -> major**, so I tried this progression :

  **Em Am | Em Am | Bsus4 B | G#m C#m | G#m C#m | Bsus2 Bm**

  **Bsus2** isn't part of both keys, but at least the resolution **Bsus2 -> Bm** sounds better. But alas, improvising a melody that sounded good when going from **G# aeolian** to **E aeolian** was still a challenge.

---

Coming back to my initial progression

**Em Am | Em Am | Bsus4 B | G#m C#m | G#m C#m | Bsus4 Bm**

I don't get how this doesn't work. I thought it could also be that **B** doesn't have the same function in both keys, but it happens to be that **B** is **V** in **E aeolian** and **III** in **G# aeolian**. ***Functionnally it should work, even if I'm only mostly going from Em penta to G# penta and back, shouldn't it ?*** Even if that's the issue, I've tried to change **B** to **G**, which is **III** in **E aeolian** *(see first point above)* but it doesn't work !

Since I've never tried modulating while improvising before, I doubt it could be my improvising itself that is the issue. ***If it is, why is it so easy for me to change from E to G# but not the other way around ? And even if it's just my ear that is not accustomed to this change, why is there a difference really ?***

I'm also thinking that maybe from **E** to **G#** your going *up a major third* while from **G#** to **E** you're going *up a sixth*, but ***I'm not sure I understand why it could be that that makes that much difference***. ***Obviously* E and G# are as far away from each other as G# and E are in the circle of fifths**.

***Is it maybe because of the relative functions of the common notes in both keys ?*** In **E aeolian**, **E F# B** are **I**, **II**, **VI**, and in **G# aeolian** they are **II**, **VI**, **VII**. I'm not sure were to go from there if that's the reason.

---

**TL;DR** : Using a common-chord modulation from **E aeolian** to **G# aeolian** and improvising, going from **E** to **G#** sounds good pretty easily, but not the other way around. ***Why is that ?*** I'm using the same method to come up with the chords, and I've never improvised in such a modulation context before, so there is no apparent reason why one change should be easier than the other.

Comment: Would you mind clarifying some of your chord qualities? Those G♯ and C♯ chords are all minor, correct?

Comment: Yes indeed, mistake on my part !

Comment: (original post edited)

Comment: I think the same problems will be there even if you modulate from E major to G# major, and use diatonic notes. When modulating, usually, the ultimate chord before the change is V of the new key. Going from E to G# (majors) will need D#(7), while returning will need B(7). Same problem, I think. That lack of leading note, as Richard spotted, is a bigger problem.

Answer (score 1):

One possible fix might be found in this sentence:

> it happens to be that **B** is **V** in **E aeolian**

I wonder if you're conflating V *as a dominant major triad* with *the triad built on the fifth scale degree*. Because the triad built on the fifth scale degree is B minor (`v`), which doesn't lead back to an E tonic as smoothly as a B-*major* triad (`V`) would.

Technically, this B-major chord doesn't fit your stipulation that you want this chord to be diatonic in the subsequent key (in this case, E Aeolian). But when I play your progression, the D♮ in that chord sticks out to me as a "wrong" note. And culturally, we're really accustomed to hearing a B-major triad move to an E tonic. This means that, just by playing a D♯ in that chord, you *really* strengthen the resolution to E and make clear to your listeners that you're looping back to the beginning.

And this doesn't interrupt your improvisation either; you can continue to use G♯ Aeolian above this chord if you like. It is, after all, the relative key/scale of this B-major chord!